# event on row press react native

Tags: react-native, navigation, onpress

How to do any action like alert or navigate to another screen on row press using 'react-native-table-component' I need your help I use the followning code

```
   import { Table, Row, TouchableRow } from "react-native-table-component";

    return (
       <>
         <Table borderStyle={styles.border} style={styles.table}>
           {/* Header row */}
           <Row
             data={}
             style={}
             textStyle={}
           />
   
           {/* Data rows */}
           {data.map((entry, index) => (
             
             <Row
               key={index}
               data={}
               style={}
               textStyle={}
             >
               </Row>
             
           ))}
         </Table>
       </>
     );
   };
```

Comment: For the time being, this function needs to be implemented through the map nested TouchableOpacity row component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put {/* Data rows */}  between  and it works fine